# Neo4j: How could I install APOC on Neo4j Server?

Tags: neo4j, server, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I need to install APOC on Neo4j Server how could I do?
I created a folder "plugins" and after I executed the following command:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

But I have this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'b': expected 'r/R' or 
'e/E' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
"dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*"^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing issues with restarting Neo4j instance after placing the apoc jar in the plugins folder: Latest version of the APOC jar doesn't work with all Neo4j installations. One needs to use the right APOC version.

For example, You can find the compatibility matrix for 3.2 version of Neo4j here: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_version_compatibility_matrix

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the APOC jar from [GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases) according to your Neo4j version by copying it to the plugins folder.
2. Add the property you mentioned, `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*` to the end of your `neo4j.conf` file (located in the conf folder of your Neo4j installation.

The error you provided suggests you didn't add the property to the neo4j.conf file, but somehow entered it as a command in a Cypher query or something similar.